# Way to override field function in v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I want to override a original field function in Odoo.

According to the answer here: [Odoo: How to override original function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32859723/odoo-how-to-override-original-function) 
i just have to define exactly the same method as in the original model. So here is my code:

```
class paiement_client_difference_montant(models.Model):
    _inherit="account.voucher"

    #writeoff_amount=fields.Float(compute='_get_writeoff_amount')

def _get_writeoff_amount(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
    print '_get_writeoff_amount _inherit'
    if not ids: return {}
    currency_obj = self.pool.get('res.currency')
    res = {}
    for voucher in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        debit = credit = 0.0
        sign = voucher.type == 'payment' and -1 or 1
        for l in voucher.line_dr_ids:
            debit += l.amount
        for l in voucher.line_cr_ids:
            credit += l.amount
        currency = voucher.currency_id or voucher.company_id.currency_id
        res[voucher.id] =  currency_obj.round(cr, uid, currency, voucher.amount - sign * (credit - debit))
    return res
```

But that code is never reached.
Any help please. Thank you.

Comment: This is possibly an indentation problem, i edited your question and fixed it, your class never _inherited from `account.voucher` because the inherit field was outside the class block

Comment: By field you mean't `writeoff_amount` . It's a comment.By the way i've tried with your change and it still doesn't work.

Comment: `writeoff_amount` is a field in base `account.voucher`?

Comment: @gabrieloliveira Yes.

Comment: @OumarDiarra i meant `_inherit = account.voucher` it was outside the class block....i edited your question and fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to override that field again in your class, to execute this newly created method.

Comment: Thank you for the direction it works now. Needed to override that field again and use compute parameter.